# Unable to pass data to another View Controller using segue

Tags: objective-c, segue

I have

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AvaToiminguAlustamiseKontroller"])
  {
    ToiminguAlustamiseKontroller*toiminguAlustamiseKontroller =
    segue.destinationViewController;
    toiminguAlustamiseKontroller.delegate = self;
  toiminguAlustamiseKontroller.dictView2=dictView1;

    self.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    [toiminguAlustamiseKontroller setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext];

  }
```

}

dictView1 and dictView2 type is NSDictionary. For some reason, the data isn't passed to second View Controller (NSLog in viewDidLoad gives null). Could it be that the dictionary is too big to be passed to the second View Controller before the segue gets fired?

Random string I tried with gets passed fine.

After dismissing the second View Controller and displaying it again, the data is present.

Comment: I assume you verified that dictView1 is non null when you assign it to dictView2 in the destination VC?

Comment: Yes, I've verified this

Comment: *"Could it be that the dictionary is too big?"* No, the assignment just copies the pointer and increments the reference count, so the size of the dictionary doesn't matter.

Comment: Can you NSLog inside your if statement and see if it is being called ?

Comment: It's being called for sure, because second View Controller does get displayed -  the problem is that no data is passed to second View Controller.

Comment: If your segue is connected in IB your second view controller will still get displayed without the prepareForSegue method

Comment: Checked - if statement is being called

Comment: Since i can only see the code you have provided i'd ask the following:

When are you initiating the segue ?
Can you try logging dictView1 inside the prepareForSegue method ?
Can you try logging toiminguAlustamiseKontroller inside the prepareForSegue method ?

Comment: Segue is initiated automatically when the device is in certain (user defined) geographical area. In code, it gets initiated from another class. I logged both dictView1 and toiminguAlustamiseKontroller inside prepareForSegue and they are not null.

Answer (score 0):

You may forgot to `alloc]init]` your NSDictionary in second class and `alloc]init]` your second class object.

Comment: I don't think thats the case. As far as I undestand, there's no need to alloc]init] dictView2 as dictView2 is a property,  thus instance variable is created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

With the information at hand this is also just kind of a guess, but could you confirm that the `NSDictionary * dictView2` property of the destination view controller is declared `strong` and not `weak`?

Also, can you check again if this property gets set or written to in some other place early in the destination view controller's life cycle?

Comment: It's declared strong. Not sure what you mean by setting the property in the early place of destination view controller's life cycle (NSLog in viewDidLoad?) and what should be the outcome of this.

Comment: Ok. I was just wondering if maybe the pointer actually gets set correctly during your `prepareForSegue:`, but then gets overwritten with `nil` at some point before you log it.

Answer (score 0):

- Try creating a NSString property in SecondVC and pass a value from FirstVC, if the string logs in SecondVC it means the problem is in the data to be passed.
- If not, try logging the data in **`viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`** or **`viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`** not in **`viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated`**. Guess, the problem is when initializing the property again, thus, becomes null.

*I want to post it as a comment, but I still don't have enough reputation. Thought, this might help.*